# VSCode gives me "Unable to import" error even though it imports the module perfectly when I run the code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using Python and I'm importing something from the same folder

Comment: Can you confirm which python interpreter that VSCode is using? If you press `Ctrl + Shift + P` and run the "Python: Select Interpreter" command, does it list the Python interpreter you desire? (assuming you have the Python extension installed)

Comment: Thank you! I did what you said and switched to a different interpreter and now the error doesn't show up anymore!